# Pausing a method until a button click

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

How can i pause a method execution or the current iteration until the user press next button for example?

I want an efficient way because i can't divide the method into other methods and I don't want to use `Thread.Sleep()` because it freezes the GUI.

```
   public void Calc(int x)
   {
       while(x < 4)
       {
           //My Work
           textbox1.Text += "Press next to continue";
           //Need to pause the iteration until taking a signal from a button
       }
   }
   void button1(...)
   {
       Calc(1);
   }
```

Comment: Execute methods in one thread, draw gui in another.

Comment: @SvSv Can you clarify more ?

Comment: Use [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @SvSv - How does that help with this?

Comment: @SvSv I think it is clear now ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can run both work and button code on UI thread, thanks to async/await scheduling. And you can reuse same semaphore instance to make multiple signals.

```
//not signaled semaphore with maximum of 1 signal
SemaphoreSlim _workSignal = new SemaphoreSlim(0,1);
```

Your work code:

```
async void DoWork()
{
    //Do Something
    //this tries to decrease signal count and if signal count is 0, 
    //waits until it will have some signals, then "takes" 
    //one signal to go through. 
    //After this line the semaphore will be in non-signaled state
    await _workSignal.WaitAsync(); 
    //Do more
}
```

Your button handler

```
void Button_Click(...) 
{ 
    _signal.Release();//increases signal count, allowing your work code to go through
}
```

Comment: It is good but only if i use it one time in a loop but if i use it 4 times ( using 4 signals ) for example the execution starts like 1st signal , 2nd signal , 1st , 3rd , 1st , 2nd , 1st , 4th. It should be executed systematically like 1st signal , 2nd , 3rd , 4th. Did you get my point ?

Comment: @MohamedShiha, sorry, but I didn't understand you. Can you describe the expected interaction between the button(s) and work step(s) in more detail?

Comment: as I mentioned before I want to pause an iteration or a method execution until i press a button. I tried your solution but when I traced the code I figured that it didn't pause the execution until the click event is fired, but instead of that It start executing the method again thats why it showed me repeated result.

Comment: @MohamedShiha can you edit the question with the code you're trying to use?

Comment: Remember, that code is inside the scope of a boolean method, so I think I can't use async

Comment: @MohamedShiha - You should post a [mcve] so that we can answer your question properly. That means we should be able to copy, paste, and run your code to see what you are doing. Oleh's answer looks good, but you've now told him you can't use it because you can't use `async`. If he had had your code he might have written an answer that suited you better.

Comment: I got you. Sorry for that coz I am new here btw I will update a suitable example for that

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple ManualResetEvent along with async method may help you:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ManualResetEvent _calcEvent;

    private delegate void ChangeTextMethod(string text);

    private ChangeTextMethod _changeTextHandler;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _calcEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        _changeTextHandler = delegate (string text) {
            textbox1.Text += text;
        };
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calc(1);
    }

    public async Task Calc(int x)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            while (x < 4)
            {
                //My Work
                textbox1.Invoke(_changeTextHandler, "Press next to continue");
                //Need to pause the iteration until taking a signal from a button
                _calcEvent.WaitOne();
                x = 4;
            }
            textbox1.Invoke(_changeTextHandler, "... continued");
        });
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _calcEvent.Set();
    }
}
```